# How can I run single command on multiple servers in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

How can I run single command on multiple servers in Ruby

example: I have 100 servers which has open connection from main server. I need to run the "find" command from main server to see what are the files modified for last 7 days for 100 Servers

Comment: Does it have to be ruby?

Comment: yes i need it in ruby. can anyone help me plzz

Comment: I guess you can run `ruby` from `python` and if you have python, I would recommend you `Ansible`

Comment: Is `cap invoke` from capistrano an option?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need some infrastructure automation tools. There many tools available. Have a look at capistrano, its an open source tool and you can use ruby. Or have a look at chef

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just need to write a ruby script that iterates the find command per server.

Example:

```
require 'net/ssh'

results = [server_1, server_2, etc...].map do |server|
  Net::SSH.start(server) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec! "~/bin/ruby find <your find params here>"
  end
end
```